# is there some special setting for servers to run jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xampp

i had an html page that run some jQuery scripts and that works ok. 
but once i use the same scripts in php page then tries to run it using local server (xampp) it doesnt working .. then i tried to upload files on linux server over the internet but neither the html nor the php pages worked right ! 
so did i miss something ? is there some settings needed to change on servers i didnt do ? 
btw: i just start learning jQuery .. and i cant move forword :/ 
help plz ?

thanx ..

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript and is executed by the browser. You don’t require a special server or server settings except for serving the JavaScript files that contain your jQuery code.

Comment: Make sure your path to jQuery doesn't reference your C:\  It should be relative to the page you are loading e.g. "js/jquery.js"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In http://reema.org/jQuery/tots/index.html, firebug indicates an error "$ not defined", so jquery.js is not being loaded.

In the HTML we have `<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>`
, but when we try to load http://reema.org/jQuery/jquery.js we get a "Forbidden" page.  The forbidden page is different from the "Not Found" page you get if you just make up a URL on reema.org.

I think the jquery.js file is in the right place, but that it has the wrong permissions on the file system.

Comment: true .. the permission changed when i upload the folder or something cuz i didn't changed any permission =) 
also thanx for firebug .. its wonderful
thanx all guys ..

Comment: BTW your HTML is very tidy.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is a client-side technology, and has nothing to do with your servers beyond residing within them while awaiting delivery.

When you have problems with something "doesnt working", you should describe very clearly what behavior you see and why you feel that it is incorrect.  Nobody can help you when you just say "it doesn't work plz help".

Comment: thank you pointly .. 
i'm new on this .. sorry for not being clear enough 
would u take a look at this html page: http://reema.org/jQuery/tots/index.html
info: i was trying to run the horizon scroll bar script which provided by flowplayer.org here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html
it was working when i open the page using full path from file://
but it doesnt work when i upload the same folders .. also it didnt work when i was trying to run the script using http://localhost ...

sorry if this post isnt clear enough .. thanx for trying to help =)